# In PhantomJS how can I pass URI parameters to an HTML file loaded with the file:// protocol?

Tags: phantomjs

I am using PhantomJS 2.1.1.  I'd like to open an HTML file on my local file system in Phantom, and pass it URI parameters.

If I open the page without URI parameters, e.g:

```
page.open("product.html");
```

Then the page opens just fine
But if I pass in URI parameters with the path:

```
page.open("product.html?id=cheese");
```

Then I get the error "product.html?id=cheese: No such file or directory" (in the PhantomJS debugging environment for product.html), as if Phantom is including the URI parameters as part of the file name.  This is supported by examining network requests in the Phantom debugger.

I've only experienced this after upgrading past PhantomJS 2.0.  Previously I was using PhantomJS 1.9, and was able to pass URI parameters in this manner and everything worked fine.  Is there some new Phantom API for passing URI parameters?

Comment: Have you tried it with the file-URI? Anyway, the URL query is supposed to be processed by the server. PhantomJS cannot remove the query part, because it thinks it's part of the filename. How do you think it should process it? Do you have so JavaScript that reads the query?

Comment: I was able to solve it doing exactly this!  I added "file://" to the path and it then processed my URI parameters correctly.  By adding file:// to the path I had to change to an absolute path, but this was rather trivial compared to getting URI parameters processed.

This is also an open bug on the phantom project:
[https://github.com/ariya/phantomjs/issues/14050](https://github.com/ariya/phantomjs/issues/14050)